# JLabel locations not working, can't select location

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I attempted to move the label to a specific location but it failed, anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Bread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame B = new JFrame();
        B.setVisible(true);
        B.setSize(800, 600);
        B.setResizable(false);
        B.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        B.setTitle("LolzWut?");
        B.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        B.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel Label = new JLabel("Test");
        Label.setText("Label Text");
        B.add(Label);
        Label.setLocation(200, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 3):

The `JLabel` is under the management of a `LayoutManager`, each time the parent container is revalidated, the `JLabel` will be positioned to where the `LayoutManager` wants it.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

The question is, why do you think you need to set it's location?